# How to use react-bootstrap in typescript project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-bootstrap

I am trying to make a nav bar using react-bootstrap I have installed the node-module which is `"@types/react-bootstrap": "^0.32.11",` and I want to use in my hello.tsx component but it shows compile error Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-bootstrap' in:\Query Express\Portal\src\components' I don't understand why it is looking for react-bootstrap in component directory

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Navbar, Nav, NavItem, NavDropdown, MenuItem } from "react-bootstrap";

export interface IHelloProps { compiler: string; framework: string; }

// 'helloProps' describes the shape of props.
// state is never set so we use the '{}' type.
export class Hello extends React.Component<IHelloProps, {}> {
    render() {
        return(
        <div>
            <Navbar inverse>
  <Navbar.Header>
    <Navbar.Brand>  
      <a href="#brand">React-Bootstrap</a>
    </Navbar.Brand>
    <Navbar.Toggle />
  </Navbar.Header>
  <Navbar.Collapse>
    <Nav>
      <NavItem eventKey={1} href="#">
        Link
      </NavItem>
      <NavItem eventKey={2} href="#">
        Link
      </NavItem>
      <NavDropdown eventKey={3} title="Dropdown" id="basic-nav-dropdown">
        <MenuItem eventKey={3.1}>Action</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem eventKey={3.2}>Another action</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem eventKey={3.3}>Something else here</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem divider />
        <MenuItem eventKey={3.3}>Separated link</MenuItem>
      </NavDropdown>
    </Nav>
    <Nav pullRight>
      <NavItem eventKey={1} href="#">
        Link Right
      </NavItem>
      <NavItem eventKey={2} href="#">
        Link Right
      </NavItem>
    </Nav>
  </Navbar.Collapse>
</Navbar>
        <h1>Hello from {this.props.compiler} and {this.props.framework}!</h1>;                                                                                                                                                            
        </div>
        )}
}
```

Index.html

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app"></div>

        <!-- Main -->
        <link href="./src/css/lib/_bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
        <script src="./dist/main.bundle.js"></script>
        <script src="./dist/nodeModules.bundle.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you included react-bootstrap in your project? `npm i react-bootstrap`

Comment: @SharpCode `npm install --save @types/react-bootstrap`

Comment: Posted answer, you only installed the definitions not the actual package

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This error usually occurs when the node module is not found or possibly incorrectly installed. So in the case that it is not found or available run the following command `npm i react-bootstrap` and then make sure it is in your package.json listed under dependencies.

If this still doesn't work delete the `package-lock.json` file and run `npm i` to install all the packages again. Make sure react-bootstrap is in dependencies before doing so otherwise do `npm i react-bootstrap` first then `npm i`

Comment: The code is getting compiled but I didn't see any nav bar, I have also linked the `<link href="./src/css/lib/_bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>` in my html

Comment: @AkashVishwakarma try add the cdn link from https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction instead and see if it work. Not sure what bundler you are using but could be that `./src/css/lib/_bootstrap.min.css` isn't getting loaded or possibly your bundler isn't setup correctly

Answer (score 6):

In my case, I just added this line to my index.tsx and after that works just fine:

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

but before that you need to install the libraries, using this command:
**`npm i react-bootstrap bootstrap`**

Comment: I had the same issue and adding your line solved it, thanks!